# A kind of imperfect field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Facts:

(1) A: finite set of combinatorial nature  |A|=n,

(2) (A,+,0) abelian group (isomorphic with Zn),

(3) (A,*,0) non-abelian group  (with same identity as + op),

(4) * distributes (left & right) over +

Question: What name could this 2-op structure have? (If any)

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: The third requirement seems nonsensical to me. If you were looking for a noncommutative field (these are called skew fields or division rings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring) then you would need to exclude zero and the multiplicative identity would necessarily be different from the additive identity. Are you sure this is what you mean to ask? Even if you fix this, there are no noncommutative finite division rings, by a theorem of Wedderburn: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem

Comment: 0 means an element from A. No arithmetic operations involved! It could be stated  as (2) (A,+,1) abelian group, (3) (A,*,1) non abelian group. Thanks Yuanfor your comment, but both ops are non-numerical.

Comment: You can't have $0$ being both identities if $*$ distributes over $+$ in those conditions, unless $|A|=1$. Indeed $x*0= x* (x - x) = x*x - x*x = 0$. Thus if $x*0 = x$, then $x=0$.

Comment: You are right Max, thanks for your comment. I am searching another operation with independent identity to build a ring for further work.

Answer (score 2):

No such structure exists unless $n=1$.  Indeed, let $A$ be any abelian group with operation $+$ and identity element $0$, and suppose $*$ is a binary operation on $A$ which also makes $A$ a group and left-distributes over $+$.  For any $a\in A$ we then have $$a*0=a*(0+0)=(a*0)+(a*0)$$ and subtracting $a*0$ gives $a*0=0.$  Now let $b\in A$ be arbitrary and take $a$ to be $b*0^{-1}$ (where $0^{-1}$ is the inverse of $0$ with respect to $0$).  We then have $$0=a*0=(b*0^{-1})*0=b.$$ Thus every element of $A$ is equal to $0$, so $A$ has only one element.